# Sorting algorithms more efficient than bubble sort

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-languages

I have written this algorithm to sort a list using bubble sort. Is this the most efficient way to sort a list?
If not, why?
What makes it less efficient and what are the alternatives present?

```
def BubbleSort(List):
     for i in range(len(List)-1):
          for Number in range(len(List)-1):
               if List[Number] > List[Number+1]:
                    List[Number], List[Number+1] = List[Number+1], List[Number]

print(BubbleSort([5,2,1,4,3])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ahh thanks. I understand there is already a built in sort function, but I'm trying to make the algorithm myself for practice, and want to understand how to make better, more efficient algorithms.

Comment: by googling. check wikipedia. come back when you are able to ask a decent question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your above algorithm, if the `length` of your array is `5`, it will execute the inner `if statement` `25` times. In general when you will have a list of `n` size, it will for sure do `n^2` operations excluding the `for loop` and `swapping`.

For a list of size `10^6`, it will be `10^12` operations atleast. `C` or `C++` do around `10^9` operations per second. So this code of yours will take `10^3` seconds which is more than half an hour. So that's very much inefficient.

There are better sorting algorithms which you can use instead of `bubble sort` as they are faster than this.

- [Merge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)
- [Quick Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)
- [Heap Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort)

A lot of other techniques are also there but these are most common used.

Apart from that, you don't need to implement these algorithms as one of the most efficient one is already implemented in standard library of mostly each language from `C` to `Rust`. You can just use that implementation and even pass you own `comparator` function if you want.