# How to check Big O notation of a sorting algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o

I don't know how to solve it's complexity and such. How to know if it is faster than other sorting algorithms?

I find difficulty finding it because I'm a little bit bad at math.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int arr[])
{
    int temp;
    int numofarrays=9999;
    for(int runtime=1; runtime<=numofarrays/2; runtime++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<=numofarrays; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] > arr[i+1])
            {
                temp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1]=temp;
            }
            if(arr[numofarrays-i-1] > arr[numofarrays-i])
            {
                temp=arr[numofarrays-i-1];
                arr[numofarrays-i-1]=arr[numofarrays-i];
                arr[numofarrays-i]=temp;
            }
        }

    }
    for(int i=0; i<=9999; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n",arr[i]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[10000];
    for(int i=0; i<=9999; i++)
    {
        arr[i]=rand() % 10;
    }

    func(arr);
}
```

Comment: You could just measure if it is faster than a different algorithm.

Comment: Since your sort function utilizes a nested loop (one for loop inside another). It has a complexity of O(n^2). It appears that you are using the bubble sort algorithm. There are plenty of [other sorting algorithms that are way faster than bubble sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317183/sorting-algorithms-more-efficient-than-bubble-sort/41317263).

Comment: Your algorithm accesses the array out of bounds, which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The big o notation is where the limit of steps of the code you write goes to infinity. Since the limit goes to infinity, we neglect the coefficients and look at the largest term.

```
for(int runtime=1; runtime<=numofarrays/2; runtime++)
{
    for(int i=0; i<=numofarrays; i++)
    {
```

Here,  the largest term of the first loop is n, and the largest term of the second is n. But since loop 2 makes n turns for each turn of the first loop, we're multiplying n by n.
Result is O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

The empirical approach is to time (`t`) your algorithm for a given input of `n`.  Then do that experiment for larger and large `n`, say, 2^n for `n = 0` to `20`.  Plot (`2^n`, `t`) on a graph.  If you get a straight line, it's a linear algorithm. If you get something that grows faster, try graph `ln(t)` and see if you get a line, that would be an exponential algorithm, etc.

The analytical approach looks scary and sometimes math heavy, but it's doesn't really have to be. You decide what your expensive operation is, then you count how of many of those you do.  Anything that runs in loops including recursive functions are the main candidates the run-time of that goes up as the loop runs more times:

1. Let's say we want count the number of swaps.
2. The inner loop swap `numofarrays` times which is `O(n)`.
3. The outer loop runs `numofarrays/2` times which is also `O(n)` as we drop the factor 1/2 as it's doesn't matter when `n` gets large.
4. This mean we do `O(n) * O(n)` = `O(n^2)` number of swaps.
5. Your print loop, is not doing any swaps so we consider them "free", but if determine that they are as expensive as swaps then we want to count those too.  Your algorithm does `numofarrays` print operations which is `O(n)`.
6. `O(n^2)` + `O(n)` is just `O(n^2)` as the larger `O(n^2)` dominates `O(n)` for sufficiently large `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
for(int runtime=1; runtime<=numofarrays/2; runtime++)
{
    for(int i=0; i<=numofarrays; i++)
    {
```

you have two nested `for` loops that both depends of the array size. So the complexity is O(N^2).

Further you ask:

> How to know if it is faster than other sorting algorithms?

Well big-O does not directly tell you about execution time. For some values of N an O(N) implementation may be slower than an O(N^2) implementation.

Big-O tells you how the execution time increases as N increase. So you know that an O(N^2) will be slower than an O(N) when N gets above a apecific value but you can't know what that value is! It could be 1, 5, 10, 100, 1000, ...

Example:

[image]

Comment: Nice graph.  If you made, can you do another with lg(n) so op can see that it comes out as a line?  Maybe n^2 and n^3 while at it.